# Connect to internet via captive portal from console

Tags: networking, internet, authentication

I use Plasma-Desktop. For some reason the packages for starting my graphical desktop are broken. I'd like to install the patched version but therefore I need to connect to the internet. Using a graphical browser like Firefox i needed to login in a captive internet portal.

I succesfully got an ip address assigned on the network, but still need to give these credentials. No console browser is installed by default (Lynx?). Can I do this without extra packages?

Answer (score 0):

`wicd-curses` is a ncurses network manager.

Alternatively you can [do it manually](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-linux-wpa-wpa2-wireless-wifi-networking/).